# For each loop in MySqL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mySQL table with 5 columns.
 * translation_id is an auto increment primary key
 * element_id is id of the post/article
 * language_code  is the language of the post/article
 * trid is the id of the original post/article of which the element is a translation
 * source_language_code is the language of the original post/article

```
+----------------+------------+---------------+------+----------------------+  
| translation_id | element_id | language_code | trid | source_language_code |  
+----------------+------------+---------------+------+----------------------+  
| 1              | 1          | hu            | 1    | hu                   |  
| 2              | 2          | hu            | 2    | hu                   |  
| 3              | 3          | hu            | 3    | hu                   |  
| 4              | 4          | hu            | 4    | hu                   |  
| 5              | 5          | en            | 1    | hu                   |  
| 6              | 99         | en            | 2    | hu                   |  
| 7              | 27         | en            | 3    | hu                   |  
| 8              | 8          | en            | 4    | hu                   |  
| 9              | 9          | es            | 1    | hu                   |  
| 10             | 10         | es            | 2    | hu                   |  
| 11             | 11         | es            | 3    | hu                   |  
| 12             | 12         | es            | 4    | hu                   |  
| 13             | 13         | nl            | 1    | hu                   |  
| 14             | 14         | nl            | 2    | hu                   |  
| 15             | 55         | nl            | 3    | hu                   |  
| 16             | 16         | nl            | 4    | hu                   |  
| 17             | 77         | fr            | 1    | hu                   |  
| 18             | 18         | fr            | 2    | hu                   |  
| 19             | 19         | fr            | 3    | hu                   |  
| 20             | 20         | fr            | 4    | hu                   |   
+----------------+------------+---------------+------+----------------------+
```

I the above table, you can see that the Hungarian (`hu`) pages with IDs `1`,`2`,`3`,`4` have been translated into English, Spanish, Dutch and French.

What I would like to do is change the original/source language to English. One part is easily achieved: set `source_language_code` to `en` for all.

But that does only part of the job. The second bit is to set `trid` as `5` if it is `1`, `99` if it is `2`, `27` if it is `3` and `8` if it is `4`.

In other words, for each Hungarian post, I need to find
the `element_id` of the English post whose `trid` matches the Hungarian post,
and then set that English post's `element_id` as the `trid` of all posts (in all languages) whose `trid` matches the Hungarian post.

```
FOR EACH `element_id` AS hungarian FROM `table` WHERE `language_code` = "hu" {  
    SELECT `element_id` AS english FROM `table` WHERE `trid` = hungarian AND `language_code` = "en";
    UPDATE `table` SET `trid` = english WHERE `trid` = hungarian;
}
```

Target output

```
+----------------+------------+---------------+------+----------------------+  
| translation_id | element_id | language_code | trid | source_language_code |  
+----------------+------------+---------------+------+----------------------+  
| 1              | 1          | hu            | 5    | en                   |  
| 2              | 2          | hu            | 99   | en                   |  
| 3              | 3          | hu            | 27   | en                   |  
| 4              | 4          | hu            | 8    | en                   |  
| 5              | 5          | en            | 5    | en                   |  
| 6              | 99         | en            | 99   | en                   |  
| 7              | 27         | en            | 27   | en                   |  
| 8              | 8          | en            | 8    | en                   |  
| 9              | 9          | es            | 5    | en                   |  
| 10             | 10         | es            | 99   | en                   |  
| 11             | 11         | es            | 27   | en                   |  
| 12             | 12         | es            | 8    | en                   |  
| 13             | 13         | nl            | 5    | en                   |  
| 14             | 14         | nl            | 99   | en                   |  
| 15             | 55         | nl            | 27   | en                   |  
| 16             | 16         | nl            | 8    | en                   |  
| 17             | 77         | fr            | 5    | en                   |  
| 18             | 18         | fr            | 99   | en                   |  
| 19             | 19         | fr            | 27   | en                   |  
| 20             | 20         | fr            | 8    | en                   |   
+----------------+------------+---------------+------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Please add the expected result. My first impression is that the query `update my_table set source_language_code = 'en', trid = trid + 4` will do the job, but I may be wrong.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: SQL is a set based language.  You don't loop your records!

Comment: @the-impaler Thanks! But the pattern of element ID's is just an artifact of the illustration and doesn't hold in actual data.

Comment: What is `language_id`? Did you mean `language_code`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, exactly

Answer (score 1):

Use `UPDATE` with a self-JOIN:

```
UPDATE yourTable AS t1
JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.trid = t2.trid
SET t1.trid = t2.element_id, t1.source_language_code = 'en'
WHERE t2.language_code = 'en';
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7MK33Adn3jZAwPRztiEBTH/1)

Since you want to change all rows, you don't need to test `language_code = 'hu'`.

Comment: Thank you kindly. This does the job for the rows with `language_code` `hu` but not for other rows.

Comment: I thought those were the only ones you wanted to update.

Comment: You said "for each Hungarian post".

Comment: @OC2PS It seems your sample data is not representative. Please improve it.

Comment: @Barmar Apologies. I have added expected output to the  question